# WHMCS not sending the cpanel details to clients

Tags: whmcs

I am a newbie for whmcs. I have configure all the necessary configuration in whmcs and my whm/cpanel are also connected with whmcs. I have tested, it shows successful message to me. But my clients getting the welcome mail, order confirmation mail and invoice mail except cpanel details.

Please suggest me what to do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if you've set the Welcome Email option for the product.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have severs configured in 'Setup' > 'Products/Services' > Severs and check that your client is assigned to the server in their hosting product

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to error(s) in the service welcome email template.
At the admin area, go to that specific user services and at the footer, click on "Resend Product Welcome Email" .
You will be redirected to the sent emails log for that client.
If it did not send, check Utilities > Logs > Activity Log .

Comment: This was the solution which worked for me. Don't know why it was downvoted

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to send the email manually, go to `Orders->List All Orders` and then click on the ID of the order for which you want to send the email. Make sure you are on the `Products/Services` tab. Scroll to the very bottom of the page where you see **Send Message**. Select **Hosting Account Welcome Email** from the drop-down and click on send message.

If the email template contains an error, you will be told after the page refreshes. If not, you will see a success notification. This at least tells you that your automatic email error isn't coming from the email template. It also helps you send the email automatically while researching for a solution to automate the process.